# Update MySQL column if value in one of two column matches

Tags: mysql

I have a table with survey data and another with data about each respondent to the survey. One table (data) has 3 fields "name", "contact" and "participate".
The other table (attributes) contains more details about the "name" and also contains a "participate" value.

I would like to update table data with the "participate" value from table "attributes", if the "name" in table "attributes" matches either the "name" or "contact" in table "data".

I wrote this:

```
UPDATE data 
SET participate = (SELECT attributes.participate
FROM attributes
WHERE attributes.name = data.name)
```

This updates the "participate" value in the "data" table, but how can I also update the "participate" value if the name also appears in the contact field of the "data" table?
If I run another query with:

```
WHERE attributes.name = data.contact
```

then this updates all values in the "data" table, rather than only the ones that match.
Your help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
update 
data as d inner join attributes as a on d.name = a.name or d.contact = a.name
set d.participate = a.participate
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update data d, attributes a
   set d.participate = a.participate
 where a.name = d.name or a.name = d.contact
```